# What is the proper way to ensure/avoid non-break with item and subitem?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, page-breaking, itemize

This is a rather basic question, but I wanted to know what the proper bracketing is or options to protect page breaks between items in 'itemize'.  That is, items can be broken across pages but not within the item itself.  Please direct me accordingly if this is a duplicate.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  % can page break here
  \item B
    \subitem Keep this with B on the same page
  % can page break here
 \item C
 \end{itemize}
```

Comment: Try `\vadjust{\penalty10000}` before `\subitem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal example would've been nice, especially since the use of `\subitem` is normally used in indices, but it looks like you have re-purposed it.  Anyway, here's one way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm, textheight=5cm]{geometry}
\newcommand*\keepB{Keep this with B on the same page }
\begin{document}

\keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB

\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item A
  \item A
  % can page break here
  \item B %
    \vadjust{\penalty10000}% <-- comment this line
    \subitem \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB
  % can page break here

  \item B
    \subitem \keepB

  \item C
    \subitem \keepB

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This allows the stuff 'in' the `\subitem` to break if it is really long, but keeps the first line of the `\subitem` with the main `\item`.  My view is that it would be bad to make the subitem stuff not break at all.  So, less advisably, compare the difference if you change the example so you have:

```
  \item B
    \vadjust{\penalty10000}%
    \par\parbox{\textwidth}{% 
      \subitem \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB \keepB
    }
  % can page break here
```

(Of course, this gets weird because of the use of `\subitem` --- are we really not in an index?)

Comment: How to do that globally, so that you don't have to add it for each and every subitem you want to have together with its parent item?

Comment: @Zelphir -- Try `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\preto\subitem{\leavevmode\vadjust{\penalty10000}}`.

Comment: Hmm subitems are still put on a new page, instead of keeping them with the item, or moving both to a new page. I guess I'll create a new question for this. Thanks though.

Comment: @Zelphir -- A new question is probably better. On the basic example here, it works. You may be doing different things (implicitly or otherwise).